# How to partially update millions of records from a large table

Tags: oracle11g, updates, large-data

I have a table called as Employee, to keep the question short I have not pasted all the columns here but for e.g. sake lets say the desc employee is as follows:

```
EMPNO      NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
FIRST_NAME          VARCHAR2(10) 
LAST_NAME           VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY              NUMBER(24)   
HIREDATE            DATE         
DEPT_ID              VARCHAR2(20) 
ELIGIBILITY         VARCHAR(2)
```

The table contains more than 500 Million records and I need to run an update on it based on the following where clause:

```
update employee set ELIGIBILITY = 'N' where DEPT_ID IN 'INS, BAN, AUT';
```

Now the current update takes more than 24 hours.

I read online on a few forums that in these kind of scenarios you should

1. insert into a temp table with no logging 
   -> I have 2 questions regarding the first step:

   a) I need to know how to do the no logging part if I choose to insert into a new table

   b) Would I have to write two separate inserts: one for inserting records that match the criteria and one for inserting rest of the records?
2. Create indexes and constraints in parallel on new table 
   -> Based on what I have read, this is the command to create index in parallel

   `CREATE INDEX {new_index} ON employee({column_name}) PARALLEL 35 NOLOGGING;`

-- Please correct me here if I am wrong

3. delete old table
4. rename the new table.

Like I already mentioned, I need to update only certain rows that match the criteria, not all. How would I go about doing that with the above recommended solution.

Comment: how many rows do you expect will be changed? How large is the table (GB)? Why it is a problem that the update will take 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

Your update statement will not work. The correct syntax is

```
update employee 
    set ELIGIBILITY = 'N' 
    where DEPT_ID IN ('INS', 'BAN', 'AUT');
```

**insert**

A *temp table* sounds strange because Oracle has something that is called *temporary table* but you may not use a temporary table because in this case your data  will be lost after you log out. So let us call it an *auxiliary table*.

```
CREATE TABLE auxtable
...
)
NOLOGGING;
```

will create a table that is eligible for nologging operations. But only if the tablespace or even the whole database in force logging mode.

You now use only one INSERT-statement to insert the data- It has to provide the appropriate data:

```
INSERT /*+APPEND */ INTO AUXTABLE(
    EMPNO,
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    SALARY,
    HIREDATE,  
    DEPT_ID,
    ELIGIBILITY)
SELECT
    EMPNO,
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    SALARY,
    HIREDATE,  
    DEPT_ID,
    DECODE(DEPT_ID,
        'INS', 'N',
        'BAN', 'N',
        'AUT', 'N',
        ELIGIBILITY
        )
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

The APPEND hint advises Oracle  to do the insert  NOLOGGING mode if this is enabled on the table.

**index**

After index creation you should chnage the parallel clause of the index

```
ALTER INDEX {new_index} NOPARALLEL;
```

or to the value that the index in the source table uses.

You can use graphical tools like Oracle Grid Control or SQL-Developer to generate the extract the sql of a table or you can use expdp/impdp to generate an sqlfile.

```
$ expdp myuser content=metadata_only tables=myuser.MYTABLE DUMPFILE='mydump.dp'

Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Sun Jan 01 01:00:00 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Password:

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Starting "MYUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  myuser/******** content=metadata_only tables=myuser.MYTABLE DUMPFILE=mydump.dp
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Master table "MYUSER"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for MYUSER.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  /mypath/mydump.dp



$ impdp myuser sqlfile=mytable.sql  tables=myuser.MYTABLE DUMPFILE='mydump.dp'

Import: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Sun Jan 01 01:00:10 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Password:

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Master table "MYUSER"."SYS_SQL_FILE_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "MYUSER"."SYS_SQL_FILE_TABLE_01":  myuser/******** sqlfile=mytable.sql tables=myuser.MYTABLE DUMPFILE=mydump.dp
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "MYUSER"."SYS_SQL_FILE_TABLE_01" successfully completed at Sun Jan 01 01:00:15 2017 elapsed 0 00:00:05

The Sqlfile will be here:
/mypath/mytable.sql
```

Comment: This is all awesome information. I cant thank you enough. I have two questions though: How would I do the inserts in parallel, is the hint 'APPEND' enough?  Also is my current index creation statement correct

Comment: would this work /*+ append parallel (aux_table, 12) */

Comment: @NickDiv Hi, I added some notes how to extract the structure. there can be a praralle hint vor the select and another for the insert. But I must leave now. I will add some notes about that later.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to achieve the above functionality if there was a join in the selection process for e.g.
FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN AUTO_DEPT D 
        ON  E.DEPT_ID       = D.DEPT_ID
        AND E.RECRUIT_DATE  = D.RECRUIT_DATE
        AND D.TYPE     = 'AD'
        AND D.STATUS = 'ACTIVE';